# Git Branching Model for parallel projects

Tags: git, git-branch

There is very common that on one git repo multiple team works and they have their own development life cycle.

For example, `repo1` is shared by two teams p1 and p2 so that created their own branch `P1-repo1` and `P1-repo2` and these two teams will create independent releases. But at some stage they need to merge their code in `repo1`.

What will be the best branching model for them?

Answer (score 0):

Simply an integration branch, which can be fetch in P1, where the P1-repo1 is merged then push back, after testing, to the central repo.

The P2 project can in turn fetch that same integration branch and merge its own P1-repo2 branch, resolving any conflict, make sure the tests are still passing, and push back.